# Ошибка при выгрузке товаров Bitrix Yandex

Tags: php, битрикс, cms, export, yml

Подскажите, с чем может быть связано?
Воспроизведение:

- Заходим в **Магазин->Настройки->Экспорт данных**
- Добавляем **новый профиль
  Yandex**.
- Выбираем основной каталог для экспорта и соответствующий
  инфоблок **Выбираем все группы**
- Заходим в **Детальные настройки**, можно
  что-то делать, можно не делать, а просто нажать **Сохранить**. Появляется
  ajax-loader **"Загрузка"** и на этом страница виснет. Ждал минут 15.

В консоли вижу ошибки:

```
Unchecked runtime.lastError: The message port closed before a response was received.
cat_export_setup.php?lang=ru&ACT_FILE=yandex&ACTION=EXPORT_SETUP&sessid=тутID:110 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'SetHead' of null
    at cat_export_setup.php?lang=ru&ACT_FILE=yandex&ACTION=EXPORT_SETUP&sessid=тутID:110
```

[image: Админка]

[image: Консоль]

Проверил права на 
`/bitrix/catalog_export`,
`/bitrix/php_interface/include/catalog_export/yandex_run.php`,
`/bitrix/php_interface/include/catalog_export/yandex_setup.php`
`/bitrix/admin/cat_export_setup.php` 
и подключаемый `/bitrix/modules/catalog/admin/export_setup.php`

Выставлял выше,чем 644, не помогло

Comment: @NikolajSarry Так-то да. Сейчас ради интереса протестировал на ещё паре сайтов Битрикса - та же самая история. 

SetHead вообще задается в \bitrix\js\main\core\core_window.js .

    BX.CDialog.prototype.SetHead = function(head)
    {
     this.PARAMS.head = BX.util.trim(head);
     this.PARTS.HEAD.innerHTML = this.PARAMS.head || "&nbsp;";
     this.PARTS.HEAD.style.display = this.PARAMS.head ? 'block' : 'none';
     this.adjustSize();
    };

Comment: Проблема осталась ((( Обновить модуль Торговый каталог либо обратиться в ТП, если обновление по каким-либо причинам невозможно. Есть другое решение...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем, как оказалось, это какой-то глюк Google Chrome Canary: Версия 67.0.3374.0 (Официальная сборка), canary (64 бит).

Проверил на обычном Google Chrome, Firefox, Yandex Browser, Opera - всё ок.